# Solr action=split AccessDeniedException error

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to use Solr's `split` action using the following:

```
curl -g "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores \
   ?action=SPLIT \
   &core=my_core \
   &path=/mnt/disks/solr-data/shard_1 \
   &path=/mnt/disks/solr-data/shard_2 \
   &async=true"
```

I've run:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/disks/solr-data/shard_1
mkdir -p /mnt/disks/solr-data/shard_2
chown -R 8983:8983 /mnt/disks/solr-data
```

But I'm getting an "AccessDeniedException":

> 2019-11-10 18:28:33.163 ERROR (parallelCoreAdminExecutor-6-thread-1-processing-x:my_core true SPLIT) [   x:my_core] o.a.s.h.a.SplitOp ERROR executing split:
>   java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /mnt/disks

Comment: It's complaining about the access rights to `/mnt/disks`, not the paths further down the tree. Not sure why.

Comment: .. initial guess because the solr user isn't allowed to access that directory because of the default access rights for the parent directory (`/mnt/disks`)

Comment: @MatsLindh even though the `/mnt/disks/solr-data` has `8983` ownership?

Comment: We're talking about the parent directory.

Comment: Thanks, though the `/mnt/disks/solr-data/shard_1`'s parent directory has proper permissions. I can try moving everything down one deeper directory.

Comment: The error message is explicitly telling you that the problem is with `/mnt/disks`, not with `/mnt/disks/solr-data` or `/mnt/disks/solr-data/shard_1`. I'm guessing the Solr process does not have the required permissions to iterate up the directory structure.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh. Do you know if that's something I could fix, or is it some constraint with Solr?

Comment: That depends on what kind of access rights you have set on the directory. My guess is that the solr user has to be able to read and access (`rx`) the directory at least.

Comment: So did you reassign proper `chmod/chown` on the parent folder `/mnt/disks` as suggested by @MatsLindh ?

Comment: I've tried `chown -R 8983 /mnt/disks` and `chmod 777 /mnt/disks`. Both still result in the same `AccessDenied` error